# a:hover para de funcionar com :visited ou :link

Tags: html, css

Fiz 5 links e os configurei para que mudassem de cor, usando `a:hover` e `a:visited`. O problema é que quando uso `a:visited`, as configurações do `a:hover` param de funcionar, o mesmo acontece quando uso `a:link`. O que exatamente eu estou fazendo de errado?

```
<div id="topo">
        <div id="menu">
            <div class="links"> <a href="#">Home</a></div>
            <div class="links"> <a href="#">Empresa</a></div>
            <div class="links"> <a href="#">Projetos</a></div>
            <div class="links"> <a href="#">Junte-se a nós</a></div>
            <div class="links"> <a href="#">Contatos</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
.links{
display: inline;
padding: 5px;
}

a:visited {
color: #e6e6e6;
}

a:hover {
color: #cc9933;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Crie uma Classe em `css` para gerenciar estes links:

```
.MenuLink {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: red;
}

a.MenuLink {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: red;
}
a:hover.MenuLink {
      text-decoration: underline;
      color: blue;
}
```

Aplicação:

```
<a href="#" class="MenuLink">Home</a> 
<a href="#" class="MenuLink">Empresa </a> 
<a href="#" class="MenuLink">Projetos </a> 
<a href="#" class="MenuLink">Junte-se a nós </a> 
<a href="#" class="MenuLink">Contatos</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

O `a:hover` apenas funciona para links não visitados, pois estamos a apontar os estilos apenas para o elemento `a`.

Por outras palavras - Ao declarar o CSS como no excerto de código do exemplo abaixo, estamos apenas a aplicar a personalização para o link `a` e não para os restantes. Exemplo:

```
a:hover{color:red;}
```

> Significa - **ao fazer `:hover` sobre o `a`, muda a cor para > `red`**

Para que o `:hover` funcione nos links visitados, teríamos que declarar e apontar o CSS para o `a:visited`, que será da seguinte forma:

```
a:visited:hover {
    color: #000;
}
```

> Que significa - **ao fazer `:hover` sobre o `a:visited`(link visitado), muda a cor para > `#000`**